# What MinGW compile flags for a release build targeting 32 bit Windows XP and above?

Tags: windows, optimization, mingw

I am currently using: `-Os -g` but I should think I can improve this with at least an `-mtune` flag, and perhaps more.

Comment: Do you want to support even the lowest CPU supported by WinXP? That would be a Pentium, so maybe try adding `-march=pentium -mtune=generic`. That's supposed to tell gcc to use opcodes that will work on Pentium or later, but optimize the instructions chosen (in case there is more than one way to implement the compiled code - such as the choice to use the string instructions or not) for current processors. I don't know how well this kind of mixing of architecture tuning works.

Comment: Yes, I want to support everything XP supports. Thanks for the comment, looks useful.